# PHP Message History (Two tables, two same colums.)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm posting here today because I'm in a conundrum.
I'm trying to make a messaging history for my custom website however i'm having trouble identifying what mistakes i am making.

I have two different tables, one named `messages` and the other named `messages_sent` and they both share the same columns `mess_by`, `mess_to`, and `mess_id`.

When a member is trying to view their history i would like it to display as:

> Member 1: Hey - ID 2
>
> Memeber 2: How are you? - ID 1

The code i am currently attempting to use to replicate said function is:

> SELECT *
>   FROM messages
>   WHERE mess_by = X  and mess_to = Y
>   UNION
>   SELECT *
>   FROM messages_sent
>   WHERE mess_by = Y and mess_to = X
>   order by mess_id desc

X = Who's it from.

Y = The receiver.

Unfortunately the above code does not seem to work accurately, so my next plan was to use:

> select * from messages where mess_to= Y and
>   mess_by= X or mess_by= Y and
>   mess_to= X order by mess_id desc

X = Who's it from.

Y = The receiver.

Which "sorta" worked, but it doesn't bring the history from `messages_sent`.

If anyone could help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much & have a great year!

Comment: @n01ze How would i go about doing a straight join?

Comment: @DimagKharab Surprisingly i figured it out, thank you for all the help man. It took me some time but it didn't occur as expected.